# Fitting unlinear function and histogram

Tags: gnuplot

please, how can I fit an unlinear function f(x)=n*exp(-u*x)+m*exp(-v*x)+b ? I think there is a problem with setting right parametrs but I don't know how they should be.

```
n=62.0139;
m=78.0149;
u=0.00663343;
v=0.04652;
b=1.34521;
f(x)=n*exp(-u*x)+m*exp(-v*x)+b

fit f(x) 'absorpcni_krivka_data.txt' via a,b,c,d,e
set xlabel "{/:Italic d} [mg.cm^{-2}]" font "Times New Roman,12"
set ylabel "{/:Italic N} [ ]" font "Times New Roman,12"
set ytics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set xtics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set key top right font "Times New Roman,12"
plot 'absorpcni_krivka_data.txt' title "Naměřené hodnoty" with points pt 7 ps 0.8, f(x)
```

Here is a file of data:
http://leteckaposta.cz/718543063

Then I have a problem with these fit:

```
clear
reset


f(x)=a*exp((-(x-b)**2)/(2*c**2))
a=120.546;
b=141.317;
c=12.5889;
fit f(x) 'poisson.txt' via a, sigma, mu

set key off
set border 3
set yzeroaxis
set boxwidth 0.3 absolute
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder

bin_width = 0.1;

bin_number(x) = floor(x/bin_width)

rounded(x) = bin_width * ( bin_number(x) + 0.5 )
set ytics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set xtics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set xlabel "Počet rozpadů" font "Times New Roman,12"
set ylabel "Počet výskytů" font "Times New Roman,12"
plot [40:120] 'poisson.txt' using (rounded($1)):(1) smooth frequency with boxes, f(x)
```

Here is a link for file of data: http://leteckaposta.cz/163981582

Tkank you very much.

**Wrong pictures**

[image]

Comment: When fitting, you must of course specify parameters used in the function you're fitting: `fit f(x) 'absorpcni_krivka_data.txt' via n,m,u,v,b`

Comment: I specified them, but how much can gnuplot vary them? I don't know the exact values, I should find them. What should I do to get f(x) go throught measured points? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I have bad via parametrs, because I changes the f(x) expression and I forgot to change it, but althrought I changed it, the result is http://leteckaposta.cz/380886034 bad